# How to wait until query is executed in Swift when the for loop is not entered every time?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if any of my user is using the same username as my new user during creating new account. So as you can see I'm using query to get documents from firebase but usernameTaken() is returning output sooner than the query is executed. I'm trying to use DispatchGroup (for the first time) but I can't manage to get the result I want.
Basically I want to change variable isTaken value once the for loop is entered.
This is my usernameTaken() function with Firebase query and DispatchGroup attempt :

```
func usernameTaken() -> Bool {
    let currentUsername = usernameTextField.text
    var isTaken = false
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    
    db.collection((K.FStore.usersCollection)).whereField(K.FStore.usernameField, isEqualTo: currentUsername!)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    group.enter()
                    print("Same username ID: \(document.documentID)")
                    print("Username used")
                    isTaken = true
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print(isTaken)
        print("Group notify")
    }
    print("82 : \(isTaken)")
    return isTaken
}
```

and this is my console when I try to register with taken username.[image]

As far as I know the for loop will not be entered when the username is not taken.
What am I doing wrong here ?
Maybe there is better way to check if username is already used in Firebase ?
thanks for your time and help !

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Firestore queries are asynchronous and the results must be handled in the callback.  You won't be able to return the results of a query synchronously as you are now.

Comment: I'm going to ask a question that has nothing to do with your question; how do you plan on querying for an existing username without being authenticated? Are the rules set up to allow access to the usersCollection by anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Your function, which makes a network call (to Firestore), cannot be synchronous—which means that it returns (a boolean, in this case) as soon as the function is effectively done. And that is because Firestore needs some time to query the database and return your documents. Therefore, your function should be asynchronous in nature, which means that it can "return" things after control has exited the function. And in Swift the best way to do that is through a completion handler.

```
func usernameTaken(_ completion: @escaping (_ taken: Bool?) -> Void) {
    let currentUsername = usernameTextField.text
    
    db.collection((K.FStore.usersCollection)).whereField(K.FStore.usernameField, isEqualTo: currentUsername!).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            completion(nil) // error; unknown if taken
        } else {
            if querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
                completion(false) // no documents; not taken
            } else {
                completion(true) // at least 1 document; taken
            }
        }
    }
}

usernameTaken { (taken) in
    guard let taken = taken else {
        return // value is nil; there was an error—consider retrying
    }
    if taken {
        print("username is taken")
    } else {
        print("username is available")
    }
}
```

I've also made the return value an optional boolean so that the caller can tell if there was an error (when the value is `nil`).